# Symfony2 route turns into querystring instead of masked route

Tags: symfony, twig, routes

In Symfony2 TWIG, when trying to generate a path like this:

```
<a href="{{ path('folder_new', { 'folder': folder.id }) }}">
```

I don't get the route I expected

Here is what I expected:

```
http://localhost/site/web/app_dev.php/Media/folder/new/2
```

here is what I in fact got from the path() command

```
http://localhost/site/web/app_dev.php/Media/folder/new?folder=2
```

Why do I get it formatted as a standard querystring (get) variable instead of a route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that I named the variable wrong.

```
folder_new:
    pattern:  /new/{parent}
    defaults: { _controller: "AcmeBundle:Folder:new", parent : NULL }
```

In my routing I had called the variable `parent` and not `folder`.

Correct `path()` should have been like this:

```
<a href="{{ path('folder_new', { 'parent': folder.id }) }}">
```

So, I learned that **when Symfony2 can't find a route parameter** matching the variable passed to the `path()` function, **it appends the variable in standard querystring** (`$__GET`) format instead of generating an error message.

Would have found it quicker if there were an error message, but I see the use of having it the way it is.

Cheers! =)

Comment: Even though I knew it, I voted up :) Please, add also a link to the lines of code, where this query appending appears.